# How to avoid N+1 query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

- User
- Ability
- PricingRule

defined with the following relationships:

- user has many pricing rules
- ability has one pricing rule

[image]

The idea is to fetch all abilities matching some criteria and for each, fetch its pricing rule. However a custom pricing rule for a particular ability can be defined on a per user basis.

Currently I fetch all matching abilities and iterate on them to either:

- try to find a current ability matching a user's pricing rule
- or default to the ability's pricing rule

I am using Rails and ActiveRecord and here what I have so far:

```
user = User.first
Ability.all.map do |a|
  user.pricing_rules.matching_ability(a).first || a.pricing_rule
end
```

Per user pricing rule customization should be done on demand by the business. The common workflow is to get the pricing rule from the abilities.

Any ideas or help to get me on the right track would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Where the `matching_ability` implementation is as follow:

```
def self.matching_ability(ability)
  where(name: ability.name)
end
```

Comment: Whats the code for `matching_ability`? You can probably reduce this to a single query, but I'd need to know that code first....

Comment: it's a simple metadata matching. Could be anything. For now it's just matching ability's name. I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "eager load" to avoid N+1 queries like so:

```
user = User.includes(pricing_rules: :abilities).first
Ability.includes(:pricing_rule).map do |a|
  user.pricing_rules.matching_ability(a).first || a.pricing_rule
end
```

You should see in the SQL generated that this adds a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to your queries, so ActiveRecord is loading the associated records in just the two queries. In particular, the user will be loaded with its `pricing_rules` and the `abilities` on each `pricing_rule`, and the abilities will be loaded with their `pricing_rules`.

However, implementing `matching_ability` using `where` may generate additional queries, returning you to the N+1 problem. To take advantage of the "eager load" in the first query, you may need to refactor to:

```
self.matching_ability(ability)
  select{|a| a.name == ability.name}
end
```

Comment: Thanks! So basically this would always load all user's pricing rules and all ability's pricing rules. Then look into eager loaded user's pricing rules to see if one match using ruby enumerable method, else default to ability pricing rule. Am i correct?

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois Yes, all correct, in addition to loading the users' pricing rules' abilities. I added further clarification above. Also, ActiveRecord can be unintuitive with which names to use: sometimes it expects plural forms, sometimes it expects singular forms. If you get an error about an association not being found, try changing plural-to-singular or vice-versa.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand this line `User.includes(pricing_rules: :abilities)`. A PricingRule only belongs to an Ability. It does not have a `has_many` relationship. Am i missing something?

Comment: So that's why I mentioned the piece about plural/singular forms. I'm not sure if it should load as `User.includes(pricing_rules: :abilities)` or `User.includes(pricing_rules: :ability)`